# Am I using the SSE resources most efficiently?

Tags: c++, optimization, sse

I have this piece of code to find how many pixels of key lie in low/high range.
The low-high matrix is generated from an input big matrix. I have to output the coordinates of low/high where number of matching pixels is greater than 150(of 256).

```
int8_t high[8192][8192];
int8_t low[8192][8192];
int8_t key[16][16]

for (int i = 0; i <= 8192 - 16; i++)
for (int j = 0; j <= 8192 - 16; j++)
{
    char *kLoc = key[ii];
    char *lLoc = low[i + ii] + j;
    char *hLoc = high[i + ii] + j;

    __m128i high, low, num;
    low = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)lLoc);
    high = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)hLoc);
    num = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)kLoc);

    // Snip
}
```

Can this be made better?

I understand there are 8 128-bit XMM registers and also MMX registers, whereas i am using just 3 of available XMM registers. Can I optimize the code to make use of all registers?

Comment: You can easily unroll your loop to do more then one SSE register output, so that you can use more registers, but most of the time, this doesn't matter much. Maybe you could post more of your code, to show what you are really doing here. (Note aligning the arrays could result in a speed up, because then you can use the aligned loads.)

Comment: @Christopher the problem is if i use unaligned loads, i am processing 16bytes at a time (16X), compared to (8X) if i use 16 bit alignment. This is what i think, i may be wrong.

Comment: byte alignment. Not bit alignment. so if you use `__declspec(align(16)) int8_t key[16][16];`, you can load by using _mm_load_si128( kLoc ), which can be a speed-up.

Comment: @Christopher i am using __attribute(..) for alignment and use _mm_load_si128 but then `_mm_cmpgt` fails with a crash

Comment: Post code. _mm_cmpgt cannot crash, when you give it registers. You can give it an address, which it then loads with an aligned load (which in turn crashes when you pass a unaligned address)

Comment: 16-byte alignment to avoid unaligned access is *absolutely* necessary to obtain best performance (unless you are completely computation dominated, i.e. your "snip" has *lots* of register-based computations). We cannot help here, unless you give *more code*! I agree that `_mm_cmpgt` cannot fail.

Answer (score -1):

When it come to optimization, don't guess, measure, and measure on target/production environment. For simple arithmetic the bottleneck is usually on memory bandwidth, so you may consider doing other things in between load and save. You may also reduce to one compare instead of 2 compare+merge result, by reorder and interleave the loop into:

```
num_1  = loadu(hLoc); hLoc++;
num_2  = loadu(hLoc); hLoc++;
low_1  = loadu(kLoc); kLoc++;
low_2  = loadu(kLoc); kLoc++;
high_1 = loadu(lLoc); lLoc++;
high_2 = loadu(lLoc); lLoc++;

num1   = mm_sub(low1)
num2   = mm_sub(low2)
cmp num1, high1
cmp num2, high2

store num1
store num2
```

You may also want to move kLoc, lLoc, hLoc outside the loop and do increment(ie. kLoc++) as above, some compiler so dumb and generate code that calculate the address in every loop.